# Use PHP to set a CSS ID from display: none to display: block

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to use PHP to change a CSS ID from 'display: none' to 'display: block' once the page has refreshed.

I have tried to apply an instruction through an IF statement but it does not seem to work.

I would be grateful for any advice and also grateful for some example code so that I can see where I am going wrong! :(

```
#successMsg {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #7ACF00;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 7;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    display: none;
}



 <div id="contactOuter">
        <div id="contactInner">
            <div id="contactInnerWrapper">
                <a href="#"><span id="close">&times;</span></a>
                <h1 id="h1contactForm">Get in touch</h1>
                <div id="errorDiv"></div>
                <form method="post" action="index.php">
                    <label for="email">Email address:</label><br>
                    <input  type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Enter email" id="email">
                    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input  type="text" name="subject" id="subject"><br>
                    <label for="body">What would you like to ask us?</label><br>
                    <textarea  type="text" name="body" rows="7" id="content"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div id="successMsg"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>


<?php

    if (sendemail('info@example.com', $email, $subject, $body)) {
        ?>
            <style type="text/css">#successMsg {
                display:block;
            }</style>
        <?php
    } else
        $msg = 'Email failed, please try again later';

    }

?>
```

Comment: In this case, using PHP is not a very efficient solution. Since it's a server-side programming language you cannot really interact with the client-side by itself. However, you can use JavaScript or jQuery in order to change the CSS display property of an element.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to only output the success message if the form was posted: `<?php if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) : ?><div id="successMsg">....</div><?php endif  ?>`. If you're posting the form through Ajax, then you should do it using Javascript.

Comment: @MarkFrankli - Just a small note about: _"you can use JavaScript or jQuery"_ - jQuery _is_ javascript. It's just a JavaScript library.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Hi Mangus, thanks for the reply.  With the code you have given is this to be placed in the html side or in the php side.  Sorry I know that's probably a really silly question but I'm new to php so learning as I go.  Also I believe I can use javascript to display the success message but I was hoping to achieve this in some way through php as then the success message will reflect that it has gone to the server and not just submitted from the user end (at least that's my understanding)

Comment: 1. How are you posting the form? Ajax or an "ordinary" post? The solution will dependent on that. 2. Is your PHP code in the same file as the HTML? If it is in the same page, is it before or after the HTML code? (it needs to be before, or `$msg` won't be set when you're trying to use it). 3. If it's an ordinary post and it's before the HTML, just replace my suggestion with your current div.

Comment: @Jason - It's perfectly valid to put it in the `<body>` as well. It's not recommended, but it's valid: _"The <style> element can be included inside the <head> or <body> of the document"_. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: It is an ordinary post with the PHP above the HTML.  I tried replacing the successMsg div with your suggestion but with no luck.  No errors are thrown up but yet the CCS property does not display.

Comment: Since you only show the message on success, you need to change `display: none;` to `display: block;` in your CSS. There's no reason to have display none on a div that will only be rendered when it's suppose to be displayed.

Comment: I made a slight amendment to the code and seems to have worked - I used <?php if ($msg !="") ?><div id="successMsg">....</div><?php endif ?> Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple.

1. Use php to hide and display the message not css.
2. replace:

   ```
   <div id="successMsg"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
   ```

with:

```
    <?php if($msg){ ?>
      <div id="successMsg"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
```

3. and write this code above the message div

   ```
    <?php 
     if (sendemail('info@example.com', $email, $subject, $body)) {
       $msg = 'Email sent successfully';
     } else {
       $msg = 'Email failed, please try again later';
     }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: on submit this places the CSS properties across the whole page and makes it look very strange so the instruction is going through but not displaying how it should.

Answer (score 0):

To this happen, you need understand that you won't to change. You will replace the variable on your code. You need start a variable in your php like $varID = 'none'. When your condition is true, you can replace to $varID = 'display'. In your HTML you just need return $varID. That's it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean?